# Scrapy + Tor + Mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, scrapy, tor

I face a problem when using Scrapy + Mongodb with Tor. I get the following error when I try to have a mongodb pipeline in Scrapy.

```
2012-11-05 13:41:14-0500 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
|S-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<><>-127.0.0.1:27017-<--denied
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/scrapy", line 4, in <module>
    execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 131, in execute
    _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 97, in _run_print_help
    func(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 138, in _run_command
    cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/commands/crawl.py", line 42, in run
    q = self.crawler.queue
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/command.py", line 33, in crawler
    self._crawler.configure()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 43, in configure
    self.engine = ExecutionEngine(self.settings, self._spider_closed)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 33, in __init__
    self.scraper = Scraper(self, self.settings)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/core/scraper.py", line 66, in __init__
    self.itemproc = itemproc_cls.from_settings(settings)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 33, in from_settings
    mw = mwcls()
  File "/home/bharani/ABCD_scraper/political_forum_scraper/pipelines.py", line 9, in __init__
    settings['MONGODB_PORT'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/connection.py", line 290, in __init__
    self.__find_node()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/connection.py", line 586, in __find_node
    raise AutoReconnect(', '.join(errors))
pymongo.errors.AutoReconnect: could not connect to localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

I am not sure how to resolve this. When I do not use `proxychains`, it crawls perfectly fine.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

---

Edit:

It's not code specific. See this link: http://isbullsh.it/2012/04/Web-crawling-with-scrapy/

This is a simple tutorial to use `Scrapy` with `MongoDB`. We are supposed to call

`scrapy crawl isbullshit`

to run the crawler which works perfectly fine. To use `Tor`, it should be called like this:

`proxychains scrapy crawl isbullshit`

Which does not work for me. The source code of the tutorial is here: https://github.com/BaltoRouberol/isbullshit-crawler

Answer (score 2):

```
pymongo.errors.AutoReconnect: could not connect to localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

It seems you cannot connect to the localhost on port 27017. Is this the correct port and correct host? Make sure about that, also make sure mongodb server is running on the background otherwise you will never connect it.

If mongodb is running in the background, remove the mongodb.lock

```
rm -r/var/lib/mongodb
```

and restart the server, something like;

```
sudo service mongodb start
```

in Debian or

```
sudo systemctl restart mongodb
```

in Arch Linux

Comment: I don't think that is the problem. I get the problem only when running using `Tor`. If not, the scraper works perfectly fine and the data gets stored in `mongodb`.

Comment: Please edit your question adding some source code, so we can have an idea what you are doing and how to fix it.

Comment: It is not code specific. It has something to do with Scrapy. I have edited my question with a simple version of my problem (I face the problem with that tutorial code too). Thanks.

Comment: It helped me to recover from crash of virtual machine. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It might be that it's trying to redirect your MongoDB connection (localhost:27017) to TOR. If you want to exclude localhost connections from proxychains, you can add the following line to your */etc/proxychains.conf*:

```
localnet 127.0.0.1 000 255.255.255.255
```

Answer (score 0):

Open mongo connection before setting the socks proxy